# Multiple jQuery Mobile Collapsible: Having only one collapsible open at any time

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there any way to make jQuery Mobile Collapsible elements close all other expanded collapsibles whenever you expand another collapsible element?

This is because in my collapsible list, I want only one item expanded at any time.

I checked the documentation, and theres an event that fires whenever you expand a collapsible. I included this in the `<script>` tag below. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this or if its some other simple way to do it. And also I have no idea how to traverse the document to close all opened collapsibles.

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h3>Item 1</h3>
  <p>Content 1</p>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h3>Item 2</h3>
  <p>Content 2</p>
</div>
<script>
  $( ".selector" ).collapsible({
      expand: function(event, ui) {
      // code here to close all opened collapsibles, but i need input how to do this
      }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple.

> jQuery Mobile will visually style a set of collapsibles as a group and will make the set behave like an accordion in that only one collapsible can be open at a time if you wrap the collapsibles in a div that has the attribute data-role="collapsibleset".

http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsibleset/

Making the final code:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Item 1</h3>
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Item 2</h3>
    <p>Content 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```